# Default value in input function (HTML) that can't be removed

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I'm trying to create a form where user will enter their phone number. Since it's supposed to be used in single country, I want country code as a default value that can't be erased, only added to. How that could be done, or maybe there are alternative best practices for such case?

```html
<form class="form__wrapper">
    <h2 class="form__wrapper_text">Just form</h2>
    <div class="form__wrapper_number">
        <p>Your number:</p>
        <!--<span>+380</span>-->
        <input type="tel" value="+380" o>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `disabled` / [`readonly`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp). Or just ask for the phone number without the country code.

Comment: @MoshFeu with readonly user won't be able to enter phone number. I want only part of text to be readonly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make sure it does not get deleted by key-up event. Code also checks for cut and selected then delete...

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup', val, false);
function val() {
  if (this.value.includes("+380 ") === false) {
    this.value = "+380 " + this.value.substr(this.value.indexOf(' ') + 1);
    this.value = this.value.replace("+380 +380", "+380 ");
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="form__wrapper">
    <h2 class="form__wrapper_text">Just form</h2>
    <div class="form__wrapper_number">
        <p>Your number:</p>
        <!--<span>+380</span>-->
        <input type="tel" value="+380" o>
    </div>
</form>
```

But I have to say, this kind of things a better done simply like:
type `+380 <input here>` then on submit just join value of +380 to input submitted value...

And CSS only solution:

```css
input {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.input-container {
  position: relative;
}

.input-container:after {
  content: '+380 ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<form class="form__wrapper">
  <h2 class="form__wrapper_text">Just form</h2>
  <div class="form__wrapper_number">
    <p>Your number:</p>
    <div class="input-container">
      <input type="tel">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: First solution is buggy (try writing some numbers in the middle of "+380"), but second solution is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you!

Comment: @OleksiiHaponiuk it is not buggy per se, it does what should do. You can fix that "buggynes"  if you leave just     `this.value = "+380 ";` inside  `if ` but then you will lose functionality if user types something after the start number, then deletes the start number the part he wrote after will no longer be attached back, input will just reset to start number. Its about what you want to be done after foul play by user.