# Adding a pound sign to an input - jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, format

Trying to format this input to display as monies, with a pound sign, I have the decimal place and 2 zeroes formatted - with the following:

```
function isPrice(el){
    val = parseFloat(el.value);
    if (!isNaN(val)){
        el.value = parseFloat(el.value).toFixed(2);
    }
}
```

Been quite stuck on this..Thank you !

Comment: Just concatenate the pound sign before it.

Comment: Can you explain the issue a bit clearer?  Did you mean  `el.value = "£ " + parseFloat...` ?  You probably don't want to change the input as someone is typing it, you could just put the `£` before/after the input.

Comment: That said, I recommend NOT putting the pound sign in the input. Put it in the HTML before the input. Otherwise you'll have to remove it whenever you want to process the input as a number.

Comment: `£ <input type="text">`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default value in input function (HTML) that can't be removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410899/default-value-in-input-function-html-that-cant-be-removed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create your own/ use the below regex to include the pound sign:

```
return "£" + value.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$&,");
```

Or

get the jquery plugin for currency formatting described [here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Auto-Format-Currency-With-jQuery.html).

PS: If you just want the Pound sign in input fields, you have to use the character code. For Pound, it is \u00A3.
So:

```
  $('id').val('\u00A3100');
```